# how to load multiple files with single HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpclient

In my Rails project, I send a request , these are many files what I need,

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/customized_bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 11:55:09 +0800
```

how to load these files via single GET  HTTP  request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the Rails asset pipeline works in the "development" environment. When the app is running in the "production" environment, javascript and css get combined and minified into a single file. Check out the [RailsGuide on this topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Could you put some of the external dependencies (the one's that you don't need to debug) into a single file? That should decrease the amount of requests the server is performing which should make pages load faster.

Comment: @Cyzanfar well, in development, it's generally not a problem because the server is running on your own (hopefully high-performance) computer, and you are the only one using the web app, so it should be loading pretty fast already.